# How to handle Back button while using DrawerLayout in activity in android?

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I am using `DrawerLayout` in my application. Now when I pressed on back button first of all it is closing `DrawerLayout` and need to click again on back button then it will redirect to previous screen.

But I want to avoid this `DrawerLayout` closing on back button. Can anyone know how to prevent this?

Please suggest me the way I am stuck on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its the default functionality so why do you need to override?

Comment: Because of my application requirement. :(

Answer (score 5):

`DrawerLayout` intercepts default `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` so just create new class extended from `DrawerLayout`  and Override this methods

something like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public class MyDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {

    public MyDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public MyDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyDrawerLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just make the drawer non focusable and it will not intercept the back button anymore:

```
mDrawerLayout.setFocusable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for Slide Activity u can easyle  handle back key
:
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Answer (score 0):

use

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

or simply call super.onBackPressed() in keydown event.

Answer (score -2):

Use the finish() function on the click of the back button

Comment: I am using DrawerLayout, and for that I need to use Fragment, I want to handle DrawerLayout not activity. my OnBackPressed called second time when I pressed Back button. Before that when I presed Back button drawer will closed. That I dont want to do